# how to find the last word in file & ignore empty spaces

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

how to find the last word in file even after word there are empty lines

the case

I tried this to find the last word

```
tail -1  /tmp/requests.txt
```

**but no output**

I try the following approach

```
 awk 'END {print $NF}'   /tmp/requests.txt
```

**but no output**

I capture the word only by **tail -6** ( because the word was 6 empty lines before the end of the file

```
 tail -6  /tmp/requests.txt
 "IN_PROGRESS"
```

so what is the way to capture the last word in case we have empty space or not

expected results

```
 echo $Last_word
 IN_PROGRESS
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just start reading from the bottom and print the last word of the first line containing at least "something":

```
tac file | awk 'NF{print $NF; exit}'
```

For example:

```
$ cat -vet file     # note the spaces and tabs
hello$
bla ble bli$
   $
^I$
$ tac file | awk 'NF{print $NF; exit}'
bli
```

If you happen to not have `tac`, just use the same logic when reading the file normally:

```
awk 'NF{last=$NF} END{print last}' file
```

That is, store the last word whenever there is "something" in a line. Finally, print the stored value.

Comment: `tac` is the GNU equivalent of Unix `tail -r`.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the last word of the last non-empty line and print it at the end:

```
awk '/\S/{ s=$NF; } END{ print(s); }'
```

No need to keep the whole file in memory to print its lines in reverse order or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '$p' example.txt | awk '{print $NF}'
```

This will get the last line of the file and display the last column in the last line.

Comment: If last line is blank, nothing to print